# How to get the params of URL in oracle apex?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have my url like this

```
apex/f?p=910:16:2997302969983::NO::P13_LOGIN_ID:2003
```

Is is possible to get it from PL/Sql(anonymous block) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `v('P13_LOGIN_ID')` or `:P13_LOGIN_ID` to retrieve the value of `P13_LOGIN_ID`.

Example:

```
begin
   if v('P13_LOGIN_ID') = 2004 then
      //Do processing
   elsif :P13_LOGIN_ID = 2003 then
      //Do processing
   end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible :

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:102:&SESSION.::NO:::&KEYCODE=NO_&USER_ID.
```

Comment: I think the question was how to `get` the values from the URL from PL/SQL, not how to format a URL in PL/SQL.